# object reference passed through constructor

Tags: java, object

Im building a relatively large object-oriented program. I have a class called `AerodynamicCalculator` that performs numerous calculations and distributes the results around the system. My main concern is that my constructor signature is getting larger and larger as I add mor parameters to it.

As shown below I already have nine object references being passed into this constructor, but I need a further seven. Am I correctly creating this object? My understanding is that you pass the associated object references to the constructor and assign the class'es local variable to the object references. If this is the case the only way to get my class properly initialized with all the required objects is to pass them to the constructor, which is leading to a very long signature.

```
public AreodynamicCalculator(AircraftConfiguration config, AileronOne aOne,
        AileronTwo aTwo, ElevatorOne eOne, ElevatorTwo eTwo, Rudder r,
        Rudder rr, RateGyros rG) {
    // ...
}
```

Any advice on this approach would be very helpful, thanks in advance.

Comment: Various strategies will be suggested, and may be the best way for you to go; but this can be a sign that your class is trying to do too much and needs to be broken up in to smaller pieces.

Comment: This is not forbidden. This is one way of doing that. There are other ways to do it, but in the end it all comes down to the specific architecture of your system, which will "tell" you what's the best way of creating the system. This question is probably gonna get closed because it's too broad.

Comment: this class actually only calculates 5 variables but has to distribute those variables to 7 objects. How ever the variables that are used in the calculation are extracted from the objects i showed in my original post. So the class dosnt do that much but its acting as a getter, system calculater and calculation result distributer.

Comment: is there any system safety or performance repercussions of having a large constructor such as i have described?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned - this may be a sign your class is doing too much, however, there is a commonly used 'solution' to this problem.

The builder pattern is often used in this situation, but it's also very useful when you have many constructors with different arguments, the builder is good because it makes the meaning of the arguments clearer, particularly when boolean literals are used.

Here is the builder pattern, the way this works is like this:

```
AreodynamicCalculator calc = AreodynamicCalculator.builder()
    .config(theAircraftConfiguration)
    .addAileron(aileronOne)
    .addAileron(aileronTwo)
    .addElevator(elevatorOne)
    .addElevator(elevatorTwo)
    .addRudder(rudderOne)
    .addRudder(rudderTwo)
    .build()
```

Internally, the builder will store all these fields, and when `build()` is called it will call a (now private) constructor that takes these fields:

```
class AreodynamicCalculator {
    public static class Builder {
        AircraftConfiguration config;
        Aileron aileronOne;
        Aileron aileronTwo;
        Elevator elevatorOne;
        Elevator elevatorTwo;
        ...

        public Builder config(AircraftConfiguration config) {
            this.config = config;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder addAileron(Aileron aileron) {
            if (this.aileronOne == null) {
                this.aileronOne = aileron;
            } else {
                this.aileronTwo = aileron;
            }
            return this;
        }

        // adders / setters for other fields.

        public AreodynamicCalculator build() {
            return new AreodynamicCalculator(config, aileronOne, aileronTwo ... );
        }
    }

    // this is the AircraftConfiguration constructor, it's now private because
    // the way to create AircraftConfiguration objects is via the builder
    //
    private AircraftConfiguration config, AileronOne aOne, AileronTwo aTwo, ElevatorOne eOne, ElevatorTwo eTwo, Rudder r, Rudder rr, RateGyros rG) {
        /// assign fields
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and effort. I appreciate it. Is there any performance but more importantly safety reasons for doing this?

Comment: as far as performance penalties - well, you will need to profile the app.  There are now two objects (of probably equal size) created instead of one (the builder object, and the built object), and the builder instance will be collected.  Safety, I'm not sure what you mean.  If the builder is not fully populated (too few setters are called), then it should throw an exception (I would use a RuntimeException subclass)

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to using the builder pattern, suggested in daveb's response, you can use a Dependency Injection framework like Spring.

Comment: DI would help to inject different implementations. It does not help to prevent too many references passed to the constructor.

Comment: depends if you are using constructor injection or method injection (using property setters).  You can do both with spring.